# How to start working with ballerina language?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-vscode-plugin

I have downloaded windows visual studio and the I installed Ballerina extension but whenever I try to open the ballerina extension it shows a message " Ballerina Swan Lake is not a legitimate application or plug in". Can someone please guid me how to start programming on Ballerina language ?

Comment: Did you download the vsix file and open the from the browser/File Explorer? 
Have you tried to install via VSCode itself. I even tried to install in a windows machine via VSCode and it worked. 

You can refer screen recording in following YouTube Link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMKVo3mqkFg

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to get started is to follow this getting started article [here](https://ballerina.io/learn/get-started-with-ballerina/).

If you would like to start with visual studio code, apart from the Ballerina plugin you need to download and  install Ballerina platform (Compiler and runtime). You can download it [here](https://ballerina.io/downloads/).

After installing everything, create a new file in VS code and save it with the file extension .bal, (ex: hello.bal), VS code should auto pickup that this is a ballerina program.

Depending on the configurations on your VS code instance you will get one or both of highlighted ways to run your program from the VS code.

[image: Screenshot of Ballerina code in VS Code]

Comment: If you have installed the Ballerina platform and extension correctly, when you open a `.bal` file you can see the Ballerina platform version (eg: Ballerina SDK 2201.1.0) at the bottom left corner of VSCode.